# How to filter out NA values in a specific column of data.matrix? (data with hierarchy)

Tags: r

I have a data.matrix `df` and I want to filter out NA values for a column `col1`. I tested different ways, but always get errors.

Unique values in a column:

```
> unique(df$test_data$col1)
[1] "not_finished" "finished"     NA
```

This is what I tried:

```
df %>% filter(!is.na(test_data$col1))
```

Error:

> Error in data.matrix(data) : 
>         'list' object cannot be coerced to type 'double'

or

```
df[!is.na(test_data$col1)]
```

Error:

> Error in test_data$col1 : 
>         $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

or

```
df[!is.na(test_data.col1)]
```

Error:

> Error in `[.data.frame`(df, !is.na(test_data.col1)) : 
>         object 'test_data.col1' not found

**Update:**

```
dput(df$test_data)

structure(list(col1 = c("not_finished", "finished", 
"not_finished", NA, NA), incident = c("NA", 
"NA", "INC-6033", "NA", "NA"), reason = c("NA", "NA", "False Positive", 
"NA", "NA")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 100L))
```

Comment: Can you provide `dput(df)`? - it's difficult to know exactly what the structure of the object is here.

Comment: @thelatemail: Please see my update. The data.matrix is large. Therefore I only extracted 5 records from `df$test_data`.

Comment: Maybe try `df$test_data[which(!is.na(df$test_data$col1)),]`

Answer (score 0):

First of all, check if you have any `NA`s in your dataset

```
test <- c(1,2,3,NA)
is.na(test)
```

If you want to remove rows with `NA` in them, you can use `na.omit()`.
However, if you would rather replace the `NA` with a different value, you could use `ifelse()`. E.g.

```
df$col1 <- ifelse(is.na(df$col1), "I used to be NA", df$col1)
```

This will replace every instance of `NA` with `I used to be NA`, otherwise keep the original value. Of course it depends on your use case if you want to remove or replace.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, `is.na(..)` returns TRUE for some rows. According to my task, I need to get a new data.matrix that does not contain NA in column `col1`. Could you please show how to use `na.omit` for my case?

Comment: That depends on what you want to do with your data - do you want to drop all rows that have `NA`, or do you want to replace the `NA` with other data?

Comment: As I said in the question, I want to "filter out" these records. But I already did it by using "which" as indicated in comments. Thanks.